# Toggle "active" class between child items vueJS.2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to know how to do it vue.js way, right now I am able to toggle `active` class on single item, when I click the other item, the `active` class still appear on previous item, here is my setup:

**FileOne.vue (Parent component)**

```
// Say that I have 5 Items I am rendering here:
<template>
  <ul v-for="item in items">
    <my-list-item :item-title="article.title"
                  :item-content="article.content"> </my-list-item>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  import Items from './FileTwo'
  export default {}
</script>
```

**fileTwo.vue (Child components)**

```
// When I click each Item the `active` class should be applied to the current Item and removed from previous item:
<template>
  <li :class="{'active': isRowActive}" @click.stop="toggleRowActive">
    <h1>{{articleTitle}}</h1>
    <p>{{itemContent}}</p>
  </li>
</template>

<script>  
  export default {
    name: 'my-list-item',
    data: function () {
      return {
        isRowActive: false,
      }
    },
    props: {
      articleTitle: String,
      articleContent: String,
    },
    toggleRowFn() {
      this.isRowActive = !this.isRowActive;
      this.showBtnReadContent = true;
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am so glad I found this question. Something I wish was covered in the docs, since they only cover conditional classes on one item at a time. I was almost wondering if this was one thing jquery was better at doing!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of possible solutions: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/28/

The main idea: if you want to handle children states out of parent state, you should emit 'change property' event from child and handle calculations inside parent. In my example I store active Li index inside parent data, and send children Boolean property `active` if the current index is active or not.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<ul>
  <my-list-item :title="item.title"
      :content="item.content"
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :active="index === activeLiIndex"
      :index="index" 
      :key="item.title"
      @newactive="activeLiIndex = $event"      
      ></my-list-item>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="my-list-item">
  <li :class="{'active': active}" @click.stop="toggleRowActive">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
  </li>
</script>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: [
        {title: 'Title 1', content: 'Content 1'},
        {title: 'Title 2', content: 'Content 2'}
      ],
      activeLiIndex: null
  },
  components: {
    'my-list-item': {
        template: '#my-list-item',
        props: ['title', 'content', 'active', 'index'],
        methods: {
          toggleRowActive() {
            this.$emit('newactive', this.index);
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Also, as you can see, `v-for` is used onto child component itself in your case. In your own example you've generated a bunch of `ul` tags instead of regular `li` items.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution~

Answer (score 17):

I usually save the id of the active item in store (Vuex) or data (in component). When the active id is equal to the item id, I set the related class as shown below example.

In the data property:

```
data: function () {
  return {
   activeItemId: ''
  }
}
```

in methods:

```
setActiveItemId(itemIndex) {
    this.activeItemId = itemIndex
}
```

Template part:

```
<ul class="ready-design">
<li class="ready-design__item" v-for="(item, itemIndex) in clipArts">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"
        class="ready-design__link"
        :class="{'is-chosen': activeItemId === itemIndex}"
        @click="setActiveItemId(itemIndex)">
        <img class="..." width="70" height="70" alt="..." src="...">
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So I don't need remove the class from inactive items.

Comment: in my opinion this should be the accepted answer! much more elegant than creating unnecessary item components or creating an event bus and emitting events